# How do i upload html documents with Amazon Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-elasticsearch

Going through this link https://developer.searchblox.com/v8.6.3/docs/searchblox-and-amazon-elasticsearch-service ,I understand how to integrate Searchblox server with Amazon elastic search.

But how do I index the website and HTML documents (that is provided by Searchblox) through Amazon Elasticsearch?

Comment: I need to show the website search results to users on my website